# c++ how to define a std::result_of<F(R)> that can handle R is void

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, result-of

When i am using

```
std::result_of<F(R)>
```

like this:

```
template<typename R, typename... Args>
class Task
{
    //...

    template<typename F>
    auto Then(F&& f) -> Task<typename std::result_of<F(R)>::type(Args...)>
    {  
        //... 
    }    
};
```

Since `R` is another function's output type, so `R` may be `void`, in this situation, there will be:

```
error: invalid parameter type ‘void’.
```

So the question is how to handle both `R` is `void` and is not?

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9d9b859ca90e928

Comment: Can OP provide actual snippet that fails but is expected to work. I feel that edits correcting this the example were editor's interpretation. [`Task<void(void)>` works](https://godbolt.org/z/C0pzDA)

Comment: @luk32 you put `R=void(void)`, and did not even invoke `Then`

Comment: @luk32 You actually need to use `Then`. Of course `Task` can be instantiated with any template parameters. Although you are correct that the usage of `Task` in the return type of `Then` has not made sense at any revision of this question.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki That is a very clear solution, thanks A LOT

Comment: @MaxLanghof Yea, I saw that after Piotr's example. Thanks. Still, original MCVE would be nice.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Please don't post answers in comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Option #1

SFINAE-based:

```
template <typename F>
class Task;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
class Task<R(Args...)>
{
public:
    template <typename F, typename Ret = R>
    auto Then(F&& f)
        -> typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void<Ret>::value, Task<typename std::result_of<F(Ret)>::type(Args...)>>::type
    {
        return {};
    }

    template <typename F, typename Ret = R>
    auto Then(F&& f)
        -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<Ret>::value, Task<typename std::result_of<F()>::type(Args...)>>::type
    {
        return {};
    }
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9d9b859ca90e928)

#### Option #2

Partial-specialization of the class template:

```
template <typename F>
class Task;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
class Task<R(Args...)>
{
public:
    template <typename F>
    auto Then(F&& f)
        -> Task<typename std::result_of<F(R)>::type(Args...)>
    {
        return {};
    }
};

template <typename... Args>
class Task<void(Args...)>
{
public:
    template <typename F>
    auto Then(F&& f)
        -> Task<typename std::result_of<F()>::type(Args...)>
    {
        return {};
    }
};
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13564a9eaaa019f8)

#### Option #3

Tag-dispatching:

```
template <typename F>
class Task;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
class Task<R(Args...)>
{    
private:
    template <typename F>
    auto ThenImpl(F&& f, std::true_type)
        -> Task<typename std::result_of<F()>::type(Args...)>
    {
        return {};
    }

    template <typename F, typename Ret = R>
    auto ThenImpl(F&& f, std::false_type)
        -> Task<typename std::result_of<F(Ret)>::type(Args...)>
    {
        return {};
    }

public:
    template <typename F>
    auto Then(F&& f)
        -> decltype(ThenImpl(std::forward<F>(f), std::is_void<R>{}))
    {
        return ThenImpl(std::forward<F>(f), std::is_void<R>{});
    }
};
```

[**DEMO 3**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a8111691231d326)